# Nautilus calling stat/file on all directory entries

Tags: nautilus, files, stat

I am writing a paper and I need to confirm something that is pretty obvious to me but I haven't seen the code that would authoritatively tell me that this is how it works.

When I open a folder in Nautilus, does it call `stat` syscall and `file` command on every regular file in that folder? I also wonder how it generates thumbnails but that is a side quest.

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus is written in C. I have not found any reference to `stat` syscall in the source code, so cannot say with 100% certainty that it does or does not use it.

Mime type of files is obtained via `nautilus_file_get_mime_type` function, which is referenced a lot in multiple files such as `nautilus-mime-actions.c` , `nautilus-properties-window.c` , `nautilus-window-slots.c` and others.

However, i could not find the definition of that function, only assignments:

```
$ grep -iR 'file_get_mime_type'                                                                                          
nautilus-canvas-view-container.c:   mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    mime_type_a = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file_a);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    mime_type_b = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file_b);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    char *mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (parameters->file);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:        mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (parameters_install->file);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (parameters_install->file);
nautilus-mime-actions.c:    mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file);
nautilus-properties-window.c:       ret = g_list_append (ret, nautilus_file_get_mime_type (NAUTILUS_FILE (l->data)));
nautilus-properties-window.c:   mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file);
nautilus-properties-window.c:   mime_type = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (target_file);
nautilus-window-slot.c:     mimetype = nautilus_file_get_mime_type (file);
```